# How to you use ClipSeg to segment images with high resolution? Does it require a retraining of the model?

Tags: deep-learning, clip

How to you use ClipSeg to segment images with high resolution? Does it require a retraining of the model?

Answer (score 1):

The model operates on images with a resolution of 352 x 352 pixels, resulting in relatively low-resolution outputs. Consequently, when working with images captured by modern cameras, it is important to note that pixel-perfect results may not be achievable. For more precise segmentations, it is recommended to consider fine-tuning a state-of-the-art segmentation model.

For more details please take a look to this -
https://huggingface.co/blog/clipseg-zero-shot